# Issue with adding AWS instances to target group and ALB with terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb, aws-elb

I am trying to create a application load balancer with 2 Target groups. The instances are in public subnet. with the below code I am able to create the resources but instances are not attaching the target group a

albmod.tf

```
no-of-frontend-attachments = "${module.ec2-app-v1.aws-instance}"
```

var.tf

```
variable "no-of-frontend-attachments" {
  type = "list"
}
```

alb.tf

```
resource "aws_alb_target_group_attachment" "frontend-attachments" {
  count = "${length(concat(var.no-of-frontend-attachments))}"
  target_group_arn = "${aws_lb_target_group.frontend-target-group.arn}"
  target_id = "${element(var.no-of-frontend-attachments,count.index )}"
}
```

ERROR

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on modules/alb/alb.tf line 54, in resource "aws_alb_target_group_attachment" "frontend-attachments":
  54:   target_id = "${element(var.no-of-frontend-attachments,count.index )}"
    |----------------
    | count.index is 0
    | var.no-of-frontend-attachments is tuple with 1 element

Inappropriate value for attribute "target_id": string required.
```

I tried to change the target_id as below but still no luck.

```
target_id = "${element(var.no-of-frontend-attachments.*.id, count.index)}"
```

Please help me to understand this issue